# meaning of parameters in parse method OWLAPI (building an AST)

Tags: owl-api

I was looking for a good parser for OWL ontologies - initially in Python since I have very limited experience with Java. It seems that OWLAPI is the best choice as far as I can tell, and well, it *is* Java.

So, I am trying to parse an .owl file and build the AST from it. I downloaded owlapi and I´m having problems with it since it doesn´t seem to have much in terms of documentation.

My very basic question is what do the two first parameters of - say - OWLXMLParser(), stand for:
- document source: Is this the .owl file read as a stream (in getDocument below)?
- root ontology: what goes here? initially I thought that this *is* where the .owl file goes, seems not to be the case.

Does the parse method construct the AST or am I barking up the wrong tree?

I´m pasting some of my intents below - there are more of them but for I´m trying to be less verbose :)

[The error I´m getting is this - if anyone cares - although the question is more fundamental:

java.lang.NullPointerException: stream cannot be null
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLAPIPreconditions.checkNotNull(OWLAPIPreconditions.java:102)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.StreamDocumentSourceBase.(StreamDocumentSourceBase.java:107)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.StreamDocumentSource.(StreamDocumentSource.java:35)
    at testontology.testparsers.OntologyParser.getDocument(App.java:72)
    at testontology.testparsers.OntologyParser.test(App.java:77)
    at testontology.testparsers.App.main(App.java:58)]

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    OntologyParser o = new OntologyParser();
    try {
    OWLDocumentFormat p = o.test();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class OntologyParser {
    private OWLOntology rootOntology;
    private OWLOntologyManager manager;

    private OWLOntologyDocumentSource getDocument() {
        System.out.println("access resource stream");
        return new StreamDocumentSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/home/mmarines/Desktop/WORK/mooly/smart-cities/data/test.owl"));
    }

   public OWLDocumentFormat test() throws Exception {
        OWLOntologyDocumentSource documentSource = getDocument();
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology rootOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument (new FileDocumentSource(new File("/home/mmarines/Desktop/WORK/mooly/smart-cities/data/test.owl")));
        OWLDocumentFormat doc = parseOnto(documentSource, rootOntology);
       return doc;
    }

    private OWLDocumentFormat parseOnto(
            @Nonnull OWLOntologyDocumentSource initialDocumentSource,
            @Nonnull OWLOntology initialOntology) throws IOException {
        OWLParser initialParser = new OWLXMLParser();
        OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration config = new OntologyConfigurator().buildLoaderConfiguration();

       //// option 1:
        //final OWLOntologyManager managerr = new OWLOntologyManagerImpl(new OWLDataFactoryImpl(), new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true));
        //final IRI iri = IRI.create("testasdf");
        //final IRI version = IRI.create("0.0.1");
        //OWLOntologyDocumentSource source = new FileDocumentSource(new File("/home/mmarines/Desktop/WORK/mooly/smart-cities/data/test.owl"));
        //final OWLOntology onto = new OWLOntologyImpl(managerr, new OWLOntologyID(iri,version));
        //return initialParser.parse(initialDocumentSource, onto, config);
        ////

        //option 2: 
        return initialParser.parse(initialDocumentSource, initialOntology, config);
    }
```

Click here to Reply or Forward
15.32 GB (13%) of 115 GB used
Manage
Terms - Privacy
Last account activity: 1 hour ago
Details

Answer (score 0):

The owlapi parsers are designed for use by the OWLOntologyManager implementations, which are managed (unless you're writing a new owlapi implementation) by the OWLManager singleton. There's plenty of examples on how to use that class in the wiki pages.

All parsers included in the owlapi distribution are meant to create OWLAxiom instances in an OWLOntology, not create an AST of an owl file - the syntactic shape of the files depends on the specific format, on the preferences of the writer, and so on, while the purpose of the api is to provide ontology manipulation functionality to the caller. The details of the output format can be tweaked but exposing them to the caller is not part of the main design.